# How can I grab the author info for each post when grabbing all posts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

When a post  or comment is made, the user author is just added by ID. That way when the user decides to update their avatar/name etc, I don't have to find every single post and comment that they've ever made and update it there too.

[image]

When I was simply grabbing the posts and passing them through as payload (without the author info), it was working fine, no errors:

```
export const fetchPostsByNewest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/social/posts')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
          dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
       };
    };
};
```

I've tried going to get the author info like this, but I can't work out a solution of how to do it all in just one payload:

```
export const fetchPostsByNewest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/social/posts').on('value', postSnapshot => {
        const posts = postSnapshot.val();

        const postsAsArray = Object.keys(posts).map(postId => posts[postId]);
        postsAsArray.forEach(post => {
            const postWithUser = {};

            Object.keys(post).forEach(key => {
              postWithUser[key] = post[key];
            });

            const userId = post.author;

            firebase.database().ref(`/social/users/${userId}`).once('value', userSnapshot => {
              const profile_info = userSnapshot.val();

              postWithUser.profile_info = profile_info.profile_info;

              console.log(postWithUser);

                dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: postWithUser });
            });
        });
      });
  };
};
```

These are the console logs I'm getting from above:

[image]

Which seems to be bringing through the right data but I just get this error:

[image]

Can you please give me some suggestions, this is driving me crazy!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Firebase API `once()` returns a Promise so your code should look more or less like:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/social/users/${userId}`).once('value').then(userSnapshot => {
  const profile_info = userSnapshot.val();
  postWithUser.profile_info = profile_info.profile_info;

  console.log(postWithUser);

  dispatch({ type: NEW_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: postWithUser });
});
```

Here is the reference to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#once